# How to get a list of EntityObject's from an EF model

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I need to be able to iterate of a list of EntityObjects that are in an EF model.

For Example..

```
foreach (System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject eObject in ????)
{
}
```

From what I can see the model context has no such public enumerator.

Anyone ever done this?

Comment: You mean you want to iterate every object in the DB? In the `ObjectContext`? Something else? Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do and why?

Comment: I need to be able to iterate of all EntityObjects within the EDMX, if the database has two tables, employees and workers, then these tables are converted to entity objects in EF. Is there a public enumerator for all entities in the model?

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Yeah i am very familiar with the ssdl, csdl and msl i was just hoping i would not have to stoop to parsing XML for this one, You would think the EntityModel would have a public enumerator for the EntityObjects

Comment: Oh, I see: You want the *types*, not the *objects* as your demo code shows. The EDMX defines no objects, but it does specify types.

Comment: @marc_s, I don't think parsing XML is a good solution as it won't work with Code First models.

Comment: @Craig Stuntz: Yes, good point, for code only approaches, that wouldn't work. Seem to be a marginal fraction of all cases, however...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here was i needed a dynamic way to iterate over the EntityObjects which are also consider types in the EDMX. I needed to list the Entity name and its properties. Thanks very much to Craig Stuntz for leading me down the right path to solve this issue. Here is the final code i came up with to solve my problem.

```
EmployeesEntities context = new EmployeesEntities();
MetadataWorkspace workspace = context.MetadataWorkspace;

workspace.LoadFromAssembly(Assembly.Load(@"WindowsFormsApplication10"));

ItemCollection itemCol = workspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.OSpace);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (EdmType eType in itemCol)
{
    if (eType.GetType().BaseType == typeof(System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntityType))
    {
        sb.Append(string.Format("Entity: {0} ", eType.Name));
        foreach (EdmProperty prop in 
            ((System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntityType)(eType)).Properties)
        {
            sb.Append(string.Format("Property: {0} ", prop.Name));
        }

    }
}
MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, I think, despite the code in your question, that you are asking for the list of entity types in the CSDL rather than a list of objects. [There's a demo of that here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399257(VS.90).aspx).

Comment: Hey Craig, thank you very much for the link. That article lead me down the right path to figuring this out. I am going to answer the question aswell to link my exact code that solved my issue because it is a bit different than the article.