# How to make list of Entity Tables

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity

how can I make a list of Entity Tables in db context?
I want to make something like that:

```
    List<???> ListOfTables=new List<???>;
```

And later:

```
var smth=(from xx in ListOfTables.first()
                         where xxx.name="aaa"
                         select play);
```

(each table has name field)

Comment: take a look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399257%28VS.90%29.aspx and this one also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214701/how-to-get-a-list-of-entityobjects-from-an-ef-model

Comment: Your example doesn't make any sense. Explain what you are tryint to do and what is a table in your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question either, but if you're just looking for type information, and you have a class derived from `DbContext`, you can simply reflect on the `DbSet<T>` properties.